# Executing a list of cmdlets stored in an powershell object

Tags: powershell

I have list of cmdlets stored in a variable `$commands` and this is the output of it:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $commands

Get-AzCloudService

Get-AzCloudService_Get

Get-AzCloudService_GetViaIdentity

Get-AzCloudService_List

Get-AzCloudService_List1
```

How can I execute the commands in `$commands` one by one.

I have tried to execute this:

```
$commands | ForEach-Object{$_}
```

and this:

```
$commands | ForEach-Object{Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {$_}}
```

But both the above lines just displays the cmdlets and doesn't execute them.
I have searched everywhere to get it but could not find it.

Comment: Add a ampersand before $_ inside the scriptblock.  `$commands | ForEach-Object{Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {& $_}}` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1#call-operator-

Comment: Also, if & does not work then use Invoke-Expression instead `$commands | ForEach-Object{Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {Invoke-Expression $_}}` as per the documentation from the link on my previous comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost got it. You are just missing out the call operator `&`.

```
$commands | ForEach-Object { & $_ }
```

To call all commands with the same arguments, add them as usual:

```
$commands | ForEach-Object { & $_ -arg1name arg1value -arg2name arg2value }
```

You might want to have a list of commands and accompanying arguments. For this you could use [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7.1).

```
$commands = @(
     @{ command = 'foo'; args = @{ arg1name = arg1value; arg2name = arg2value } }
     @{ command = 'bar'; args = @{ arg1name = arg1value; arg2name = arg2value } }
)

$commands | ForEach-Object { 
    $theArgs = $_.args
    & $_.command @theArgs
}
```

Note that I had to assign the arguments to a variable first, because splatting does not work with member access. It requires a single variable name after the `@`.